# user gives full names ages amka(html javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function createPerson() {
  var fullname = document.getElementById('inputValueFullname').value;
  var age = document.getElementById('inputValueAge').value;
  var amka = document.getElementById('inputValueAmka').value;

  function person(fullname, age, amka) {
    this.fullname = fullname;
    this.age = age;
    this.amka = amka;
  }
  var NewPerson = new person(name, age, amka);

  console.log(NewPerson);
}
```

```html
<label>Fullname: <input type="text" id="inputValueFullname"></label>
<label>Age:<input type="text" id="inputValueAge"></label>
<label>Amka:<input type="text" id="inputValueAmka"></label>
<button id="btn" onclick="createPerson();">Add</button>
```

I want someone to help me with 2 problems

1. the user gives full name age and amka and I want them all to appear below in a list as in the photo below

[image]

I have a code that I tried separately but I do not know how to put them together

2. i want when someone give age<18 to stop to take more inputs
   to use for this for or if and how to do it

```js
function publishToTable() {
  const fullname = document.getElementById('fullname').value;
  const age = document.getElementById('age').value;
  const amka = document.getElementById('amka').value;
  const error = document.getElementById('error');

  if (fullname && age && amka) {
    const tableElement = document.getElementById('table');
    const trElement = document.createElement('tr');
    const tbodyElement = document.createElement('tbody');
    const fullnameEle = document.createElement('td');
    const ageEle = document.createElement('td');
    const amkaEle = document.createElement('td');
    fullnameEle.innerHTML = fullname;
    ageEle.innerHTML = age;
    amkaEle.innerHTML = amka;
    trElement.appendChild(fullnameEle);
    trElement.appendChild(ageEle);
    trElement.appendChild(amkaEle);
    tbodyElement.appendChild(trElement);
    tableElement.appendChild(tbodyElement);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="complete">
  <div class="form">
    <label>Fullname: <input id="fullname" type="text"></label>
    <label>Age: <input id="age" type="text"></label>
    <label>AMKA: <input id="amka" type="text"></label>
    <span id="error"></span>
    <button onclick="publishToTable()">Submit</button>
  </div>
  <div id="tables">
    <table id="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name/Surname</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>AMKA</th><br><br><br><br><br>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Start by passing fullname: `new person(fullname, age, amka);`

Comment: You need this? `if (age && age>= 18 && fullname && amka) {`

Comment: thanks for your interest....i try to do this:



Create a web page using HTML and JavaScript. On the website where your name will appear.

· Fill in a table with Student Objects.

· These objects have 3 fields (fullname, age, amka). The creation of these objects will be done

using Constructor (Note the fullname field is the name and is given as follows:

"First name - Last name"

· The table that is filled until an object is given under the age of 18. ATTENTION this object does not

will be inserted in the table.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use an array.

I have made some other recommended changes, such as using an eventListener and an Array.map

```js
const person = (fullname, age, amka) => ({ fullname, age, amka }); // return an object, shorthand for { "fullname": fullname  .... 

const persons = [];
const error = document.getElementById('error');
const tableElement = document.getElementById('table');
const fullnameField = document.getElementById('fullname')
const ageField = document.getElementById('age')
const amkaField = document.getElementById('amka')


const publishToTable = () => tableElement.innerHTML = persons
  .map(({ fullname, age, amka }) => `<tr><td>${fullname}</td><td>${age}</td><td>${amka}</td></tr>`).join("");


document.getElementById("save").addEventListener("click", e => {
  let fullname = fullnameField.value;
  let age = +ageField.value; // cast to number
  let amka = amkaField.value;
  if (isNaN(age) || age < 18) {
    ageField.focus();
    error.innerHTML = "Incorrect age (18 minimum)"
    return; // stop
  }
  error.innerHTML = "";
  persons.push(person(fullname, age, amka));
  fullnameField.value = ageField.value = amkaField.value = ""; // reset
  fullnameField.focus()
  publishToTable();
})
```

```html
<div class="complete">
  <div class="form">
    <label>Fullname: <input id="fullname" type="text"></label>
    <label>Age: <input id="age" type="text"></label>
    <label>AMKA: <input id="amka" type="text"></label>
    <span id="error"></span>
    <button type="button" id="save">Save</button>
  </div>
  <div id="tables">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name/Surname</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>AMKA</th><br><br><br><br><br>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="table">
    </table>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your help you help me a lot...i want one more think how can i do invisible the save when user give age<18 because i want to stop to take more inputs..thanks again

Comment: const element = document.getElementById('save'); 
    element.remove();
thanks a lot my friend